# how to toggle ui elements within an express node.js app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, user-interface

I have a navbar I was coding up in codepen with just html, css, and javascript and I am now trying to incorporate it into my app i have created with express, and node js but I am having issues and am not sure how to get the navigation burger in the header to work because the js code I have is using DOM. The way I have it set up right now is not working the code is shown below. I am using bulma css.

errors in console

[image]

code for rending the navburger toggle

```
     const burger = document.getElementById('burger');
  burger.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    console.log('BURGER CLICK');
  });
```

file for the page layout. note: i have the script src for the js file at the bottom.

```
module.exports = ({ content }) => {
  return `
      <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">
        <head>
          <meta charset="utf-8">
          <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
          <title>snack attack</title>
          <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/remixicon@2.5.0/fonts/remixicon.css" rel="stylesheet">
          <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
          <link href="/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.7.5/css/bulma.min.css"></link>
          <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
          <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
          <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Quicksand:wght@300;600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        </head>
  
        <body>
        <header>
          <nav class="navbar has-background-light" role="navigation" aria-label="main navigation">
            <div class="navbar-brand">
              <a class="navbar-item" href="/">
                <h3 class="title">Snack Attack</h3>
              </a>
              
              <a role="button" id="burger" class="navbar-burger" aria-label="menu" aria-expanded="false" data-target="navbar-content">
                <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
              </a>
            </div>

          <div id="navbar-content" class="navbar-menu is-centered">
              <div class="navbar-start">
                <a class="navbar-item">
                  Home
                </a>
              <a class="navbar-item" href="/">
                Products
              </a>
            </div>
    
            <div class="navbar-end">
              <div class="navbar-item">
                <div class="buttons">
                    <a  href="/cart">
                      <i class="ri-shopping-bag-line"></i>
                    </a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          </nav>
        </header>
        
          ${content}
          
        <footer class="footer navbar-top">
                <div class="container navbar-container">
                  <div>
                    <ul class="social">
                      <li>
                        <a href=""><i class="fa fa-phone"></i>+1 555 987 6543</a>
                      </li>
                      <li>
                        <a href=""><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> shop@myshop.com</a>
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                  <div>
                    <ul class="social">
                      <li><a href=""><i class="fab fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
                      <li><a href=""><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                </div>
        </footer>
        <script src="navburgerhelper.js"></script>
        </body>        
      </html>
    `;
};
```

index.js

```
require('dotenv').config();
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const authRouter = require('./routes/admin/auth');
const productsAdminRouter = require('./routes/admin/products');
const productsRouter = require('./routes/products');
const cartsRouter = require('./routes/carts');
const session = require('express-session');

const app = express();

app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));



app.use(authRouter);
app.use(productsAdminRouter);
app.use(productsRouter);
app.use(cartsRouter);

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log('Server listening on http://localhost:' + PORT);
});
```

project set up:

```
app/views/layout.js 
app/navburgerhelper.js
app/index.js
```

Comment: Express is your server. Your UI runs on the client. What the page does in the browser has nothing to do with what Express does: all Express does is send data on request, tied to URLs. Having said that, a note on your code: don't generate html using string, use a templating solution paired with [res,render()](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.render). You get EJS for free, if you need something more complicated, there are plenty of options for you to (re)search.

Comment: I am just confused as to why its no longer working when the code was working on code pen? is bulma not compatible with express/node?

Comment: Then it's time to maybe take a short Express tutorial: the error is telling you that you're trying to load a .js file but that file is being sent as "plain text" so the browser goes "something fishy is going on here" and it's right: you told Express your static asset dir is `public`, so why is your navburgerhelper.js not in the public dir?